# Is my Entity Framework generated SQL executing twice?

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, automapper, sql-server-profiler

I'm looking at analysing the performance of the SQL generated from Entity Framework 1, using MS SQL 2008.

When I run a trace in SQL Server Profiler 2008, I noticed something that I didn't expect. For each query that gets executed, I get two `RPC:Completed` statements, separated by an `exec sp_reset_connection statement`. Is this the expected behavior?

[image: SQL Server Profiler Results]

Comment: Can you post the code you are running?

Comment: @ajcvickers The system I'm dealing with is rather large, so supplying the code as-is won't be possible, it will take me some time to get a prototype together. I take it that this is not what you'd expect either then?

Comment: Every time a LINQ to Entities query is enumerated (e.g. with ToList()), then the query is executed against the database. I was wondering if it was this.

Comment: are you binding it to a grid? I found when I bind a grid to a entity query without a .tolist() then it is executed several times.

Comment: I'm not using a grid (I assume you mean a .net Data Grid or similar) - My presentation layer is built using .net MVC and I'm going through a Service Layer, which in tern uses a Repository. From your questions, it sounds as though you agree with me when you think my queries might be running twice - I'll do some serious investigation now..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer: **Yes**

It turns out that it was a "feature" within [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) that was causing my issue.

See here: [When Mapping an IQueryable I see the database getting hit twice in my profiler.](http://groups.google.com/group/automapper-users/browse_thread/thread/fc7c88c96fd36587)

Unfortunately because I'm using version 1.1 (.net 3.5) this doesn't look like it's going to get fixed.

**Solution:** call `.ToList()` on the IQueryable object *before* passing it into the `Mapper.Map()` method. Allowing the Mapper to enumerate the object causes a double execution.